# How is it possible to connect multiple devices using the same IP to a machine with multiple interfaces and have them all work?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nat, vlan, network-namespace

Long story short, I am a bit over my head with this task as I'm not incredibly well versed in networking and complicated network config. I have a few ideas, but want to avoid wasting time.

**Background:**
I am trying to set up an Ubuntu desktop (test server) such that it has 8 physical ports for Ethernet connection, which all show up as separate interfaces, and are effectively independent. This is needed because I would like to use a single desktop to test multiple gigabit Ethernet devices, which right now is done through multiple computers. All of the devices at this stage of production use the same IP/subnet settings. I could change them for this test and change back after, but that introduces a new failure and a ton of overhead time/setup.

**Current state:**
With that in mind, I have set up a desktop with 2x [this NIC](https://a.co/d/4IskB8X). Ubuntu detects each port correctly as enp1s0f[0...3] and enp5s0f[0...3] and I have configured each with an IP X.X.X.[1...8] and subnet 255.255.255.0. Not knowing much about what to expect, I tried connecting two devices with the same IP (X.X.X.21) to different physical ports and tried pinging. The machine connected first is able to ping the address of both connected interfaces, while the other can reach neither. Makes sense I guess, the incoming ping says it should go back out to the .21 address, and since that address is present at both interfaces, its routed to the first one connected.

**Ideas:**

- Using docker to help?
  These tests are run out of docker right now anyway, so for a minute I thought perhaps I could somehow 'bind' instances of docker to specific IP addresses, which by extension should bind them to the interface/port which that IP address is assigned to. My little ping test above is making me less confident I'll get away with something so easy, but I will probably try this first since it doesnt seem too time consuming.
- [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/350919/985135) (VLANS/NAT config)
  The question sounds like about what I'm trying to do. I would like to avoid adding more hardware but it seems like it could be accomplished with VLANs/NAT edits, but I could use slightly more information on what exactly this would look like in my case though as the answer is too vague for me to know where to start with it.
- Network Namespaces/VLANs
  This was the first thing I saw being suggested when googling/asking chatGPT, but it seemed like a lot of those use cases are for having the same IP assigned to multiple interfaces (the opposite of what I need to do?) If I am misunderstanding how they could be useful here, I would love some clarification.

**Quick Update:**
I was able to get some really basic functionality close to what I need using network namespaces:

```
sudo ip netns add test1
sudo ip netns add test2

sudo ip link set enp1s0f1 netns test1
sudo ip link set enp1s0f2 netns test2

sudo ip netns exec test1 ip addr add X.X.X.1/24 dev enp1s0f1
sudo ip netns exec test2 ip addr add X.X.X.2/24 dev enp1s0f2

sudo ip netns exec test1 ip link set enp1s0f1 up
sudo ip netns exec test2 ip link set enp1s0f2 up
```

This at least got me to the point where I could connect two laptops with the same IP to two ports on the same NIC and ping to/from both of them as expected. Still have a bit of configuration/verification to do before I call this solved but seems to be the most promising so far

For completeness, some more information about the setup I am trying to configure:

```
$ lspci | awk '/[Nn]et/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7a70 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0094
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
01:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Ethernet Controller I225-V
    Kernel driver in use: igc
    Kernel modules: igc
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
05:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
05:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Beijing Sinead Technology Co., Ltd. I350 Gigabit Network Connection
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
```

```
ip link list 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:63:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7c:16:df:45:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:63:23 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp1s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:63:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp1s0f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:63:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enp5s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:61:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: enp5s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:61:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: enp5s0f2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:61:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: enp5s0f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:b7:85:01:61:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5e:a9:4e:21:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
12: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:f0:6e:f3:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 0):

For each device that has a mac address you need to assign a seperate ip. Or setup simple dhcp server and assign the ips dynamically. You can't assign the same ip to two different devices,that will create a conflict.An IP address is assigned to a network interface (like an Ethernet device) to uniquely identify it on a network. When data is sent to a specific IP address, the Ethernet device uses its MAC address to locate the appropriate hardware on the local network and deliver the data to the correct destination. This process involves protocols like ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) to map IP addresses to MAC addresses within the local network. The combination of IP addresses and MAC addresses enables communication between devices on a network.

If you need to test a lot of Ethernet devices, I would get a 24 ports switch or something like that instead of a desktop [https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-24-Port-Gigabit-Rackmount-TL-SG1024S/dp/B0779R9LJ3?ref_=ast_sto_dp&th=1&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0779R9LJ3)

You probably also need to setup up some static routing tables to route to the appropriate network port

Answer (score 0):

You might look into bonding ports together.  It might be necessary for switch support to make this work as you desire.